# android sqlite update

Tags: android, sqlite

at first...I don't want it change my PRIMARY KEY....

and here's the create method of my DB....

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE =
        "create table userData ("
            + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "HTTPorS TEXT,"
            + "IPHostName TEXT,"
            + "port TEXT,"
            + "userName TEXT,"
            + "password TEXT,"
            + "saveOption TEXT"
        + ");";
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_TABLE);
}
```

and this is how I add row in it

```
    public long create(String HTTPorS, String IPHostName, String port, String userName, String password, String saveOption) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("HTTPorS", HTTPorS);
    args.put("IPHostName", IPHostName);
    args.put("port", port);
    args.put("userName", userName);
    args.put("password", password);
    args.put("saveOption", saveOption);
    return db.insert("userData", null, args);
}
```

Both 2 methods up before work fine...But when I want to change Value of rows...
I use this Method

```
    public void update(long rowId,String httporS, String IP,String Port,String userName,String password) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("HTTPorS", httporS);
    args.put("IPHostName", IP);
    args.put("port", Port);
    args.put("userName", userName);
    args.put("password", password);
    args.put("saveOption", "no use");
     db.update("userData",  
    args,               
    "_id=" + rowId,         
    null                
    );
}
```

It runs normal,and the correct values 「do」 get in this Method...

but the db's data didn't replace

why is that?

thanks for your help!

Comment: I think your problem is with the whereclause you have given. Check this by returning an int value from your method.

Comment: Are you sure `rowId` is correct?

Comment: What does `db.update` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_id is an **INTEGER**

Your rowId should be modified to an ***integer*** to update the db.

```
public void update(long rowId,String httporS, String IP,String Port,String userName,String password)
```

long -> int

Answer (score 1):

```
 //decleration
 EventDataSQLHelper eventsData;
    SQLiteDatabase dbx ;
    SQLiteDatabase rdbx;
     ContentValues values;

//onCreate

 dbx = eventsData.getWritableDatabase();    
        rdbx = eventsData.getReadableDatabase();
      values=new ContentValues();

//updated values
 values2.put("clumnname1", updatedvalue1);
values2.put("clumnname2", updatedvalue2);
values2.put("clumnname3", updatedvalue3);
values2.put("clumnname4", updatedvalue4);
values2.put("clumnname5", updatedvalue5);
...
...
...

//delete query   

//specify the id of the record to be updated
dbx.update("tablename", values2, "id="? , null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a writeable version of your database like

```
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: I already use this....
SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

and there's no error message....